# C# Display a tooltip on disabled textbox (Form)

Tags: c#, textbox, controls, tooltip

I am trying to get a tooltip to display on a disabled textbox during a mouse over. I know because the control is disabled the following won't work:

```
private void textBox5_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // My tooltip display code here
}
```

How can I get the tooltip to display on a mouse over of a disabled control?

Many thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MouseHover wont fire if control is disabled. Instead you can check in Form MouseMove event whether you hover the textbox

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
        toolTip.InitialDelay = 0;
    }

    private ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
    private bool isShown = false;

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox1 == this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location))
        {
            if(!isShown)
            {
                toolTip.Show("MyToolTip", this, e.Location);
                isShown = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            toolTip.Hide(textBox1);
            isShown = false;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: One further thought - how would this be applied to a textbox within a groupbox?

Comment: then you should sign for groupBox MouseMove Event and do the same thing as for Form

Comment: This is can be more reliable: `textBox1.Name == this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location).Name`

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but had the same problem and found a better solution: you can just wrap your TextBox in another Item and put a ToolTip on it like:

```
<Grid ToolTip="ToolTip to display">
            <TextBox  IsEnabled="False" Text="Text to display" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also drag a ToolTip object from the Toolbox in designer onto the form.
Then in the code you just call SetToolTip() and pass in the button or text box etc. you want the tool tip to assign to and the text you want it to show.

```
myToolTip.SetToolTip(myTextBox, "You just hovered over myTextBox!");
```

Comment: Except when the control is disabled you won't see a tool tip. That's the point of his question.