# How to disaply ToolTip on a disabled Button in windows form application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a button which is disabled on some cases,

[image]

now I want to display a tooltip text when the user moves the mouse over the disabled button, I've tried two events **Mouse Hover** & **Mouse Move**, noticed that it won't fire any events for the disabled button.

as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7888028/1463551), it seems it'll work, but since I have too may controls on my Form, I'm slightly concerned to use this method due to the performance factor.

---

Is there any better way of handling this issue?? your thoughts on this would be much appreciated, many thanks...:)

Comment: I don't think it will have much affect on your GUI performance. There is a slightly better version posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732140/c-problem-displaying-tooltip-over-a-disabled-control

Comment: Have you tried the proposed solution? (i.e. have you checked if there really IS a performance problem?) If not try it, and if it works you don't have any problem to solve ;-)

Comment: Thanks Eshan & Treb, I have tried the above solution & didn't check the performance yet, the target machine would be using XP & it's dual core machine, I was thinking if there's any option like region wise events, just for betterment of my solution??

Comment: @San I don't think thee is any performance issue with the solution from the link you posted. Just a little code in only 1 `MouseMove` event handler for your form, the code just shows or hides the tooltip so there won't any performance issue here.