# Forcefully show tooltip on "Enable=false" control

Tags: c#, checkbox, tooltip, c#-3.0

**How to forcefully show tooltip on "Enable=false" control**.

I have a **checkbox** which is **enabled false** but i want to **still show tooltip on it**. is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this windows application or web?

Comment: This is for Windows applications  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887817/c-sharp-display-a-tooltip-on-disabled-textbox-form

Comment: This is for Windows Forms or WPF? Any question involving UI's needs to specify the framework used.

Comment: Mr. @KrushnakantLadani i am searching the exact thing but when i tried "this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location)" always returned null value [note my checkbox is present in a panel and i have already tried "panel5.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location)"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from the CheckBox control itself, it will no longer receive any mouse messages.  Its Parent will now get them.  Which gives you a hack around this restriction:

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (checkBox1.Bounds.Contains(e.Location)) {
            toolTip1.Show("yadayada", this);
        }
    }
```

Strictly for entertainment, I have to recommend that you don't do this.